# Выборка данных из первой таблицы в зависимости от второй

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Не знаю насколько понятен заголовок объясню так. Есть две таблицы. В таблице №1 хранятся полное наименование болезни и международный код болезни. В таблице №2 хранятся id пациента, полное наименование болезни, номер больного зуба и т д. На экран надо вытащить только международный код болезни.  Делаю выборку из таблицы №2 (чтобы знать какому пациенту и какому зубу принадлежит какая болезнь) вот таким образом

```
<?php  $result54 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM personal043 WHERE card_id=$id AND zubno=$zubnum") 
            or die(mysqli_error());         
             ?> 
       <?php    while($row54 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result54)) {
           echo $row54['naimenov']; 

      } ?>
```

здесь `echo $row54['naimenov'];` показывает полное название болезни. Как сделать чтоб в зависимости от полного названия в таблице №2 выбрать сокращенный код болезни из таблицы №1 и вывести на экран ?

PS в таблице №1 есть поля id, kod, naimenovanie

[image: Таблица№1]

[image: Таблица№2]

1-2 таблицы

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите пример таблиц и данных

Comment: Спасибо за отклик , привел скрины

Answer (score 2):

С помощью LEFT JOIN наименования болезни из двух таблиц

```
"SELECT table1.kod FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.naimenovanie = table2.naimenov WHERE table2.card_id = $id AND table2.zubno = $zubnum";
```

Посмотрите что-то в этом. Мог напутать

Comment: спасибо за помощь как раз прочитал про LEFT JOIN и посмотрел Ваш запрос. Решил проблему !

Comment: @AlexStassov пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Болезни.НужныеПоля, Пациенты.НужныеПоля
FROM Болезни, Пациенты
WHERE Болезни.ПолноеНаименованиеБолезни = Пациенты.ПолноеНаименованиеБолезни
  AND (другие условия отбора)
```

Comment: Простите что имели виду под словом Болезни ( проошу прощения что то торможу ((

Comment: Таблицу №1, есссно.